# Bitwise Left shift and Right shift Calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript

i really need help with bitwise calculation. plz help me , our teacher asked to find the answer to a simple calculation . (bitwise) 4<<5 , 3>>3 . how do we calculate this without the use of a computer.

Edit 1:

Please also mention how to perform 3 & 4 and 3|3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a << b = a · 2<sup>b</sup>
a >> b = a / 2<sup>b</sup> = a · 2<sup>-b</sup> (dropping any decimals)

So to calculate 4 << 5, you need to double 4 five times: 4 · 2<sup>5</sup> = 4 · 32 = 128. Similarly for 3 >> 3.

Comment: and "a >>> b" equivalent?

Comment: @user1243068 I'm assuming you mean the unsigned shift in some languages. It just treats a signed number as unsigned, effectively adding 2^32 or 2^64 to the number if it is negative.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the algorithm md5 from javascript: output += String.fromCharCode((input[i>>5] >>> (i % 32)) & 0xFF);

Comment: `>>>` will shift all bits, including the sign-bit, filling with zeros from the left. `>>` will replicate the sign-bit, filling with the sign-bit from the left. Read ["Two's complement"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a simple explanation:
2 in binary is 0010.
When you left shift twice on 2, we get 1000, which results in 8(decimal)

Similarly 4 in binary is 0100
When you left shift it 5 times , we get 10000000,

On the other hand, 3 in binary is 0011,
when we right shift thrice on 3 it gives us 0000, hence it results in 0(decimal).

If you don't know to convert binary to decimal or vice versa, try google.

AND - OR:

in AND,
    0&0 = 0,
    1&0 = 0,
    0&1 = 0,
    1&1 = 1

in OR,
    0|0 = 0,
    1|0 = 1,
    0|1 = 1,
    1|1 = 1

So 3&4 will be,
    0011 & 0100 = 0000

3|3 will be,
    0011 | 0011 = 0011

Answer (score 1):

4 = 0100 
4<<5 = 010000000
=1*2^7 = 128

3 = 011 3>>3 = 000 = 0

**[Right Shift](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2ay192e.aspx)**

**[Left Shift](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xftzc7e.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

here is an example for a left shift

```
 9 (base 10):      00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
                   --------------------------------
 9 << 2 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000100100 (base 2) = 36 (base 10)
```