# In PHP What would be the output of print 4 << 5 operations?

Tags: php

I had a question in one interview, and still now I didn't get it's answer,
What would be the output of `print 4 << 5` operations in `PHP` ?

It's answer 128 I know, but how it is, please explain me

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: [Read the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Comment: 4 decimal is 100 binary; 100 binary << 5 = 10000000 binary; 10000000 binary is 128 decimal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164019/bitwise-left-shift-and-right-shift-calculation-in-javascript

Comment: @MarkBaker, still not getting friend :(

Comment: @user - to start any simpler, I need to ask if you know what binary is, and what decimal is

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is a bitwise operator

if you read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

It will start to make sense.